# Multiple Conditions for Child Page Title

Tags: title, conditional-tags, child-pages, children, get-the-title

I've been trying to work with [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and cannot wrap my head around this problem. PHP novice here.

On sub-pages I need to display the parent page title as well as the page title. I have it working with this:

```
<h1><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);?></h1>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

But the problem I have now is that on the parent pages the page title is displayed twice, as the parent page title and the page title. Instead, when on a parent page, I need the `h2` to display "Select a sub-page", if there are child pages...or display nothing, if there are no child pages. Something like this is what I'm thinking is possible:

```
<h1><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);?></h1>
<h2>
  <?php 
    if is_parent_page_without_children() {echo '';} ;
    elseif is_parent_page_with_children() {echo 'select a sub-page';} ;
    else the_title();
  ?>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the [Conditional Tags codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page), section 2.12:

> "Note: There is no function to check if a page is a sub-page. We can
>   get around the problem:

```
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 ) { 
   echo "This is a child page";
}
```

So I've altered it as below and will just use the wp_list_pages function's "title_li" attribute to display "select a sub-page" (not exactly what I was looking for but simple enough and I can work with it for the design of the website I need it for).

```
<h1><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);?></h1>
<h2><?php if (is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 ) { the_title();}?></h2>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment exchange, here's what I think you're after:

```
<h1><?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID ) ?></h1>

<?php if ( $list = wp_list_pages( "echo=0&child_of=$post->ID" ) ) : ?>

    <h2>Select a sub-page</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $list ?>
    </ul>

<?php elseif ( $post->parent ) : ?>

    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. But I'm not needing to display the list of pages, so I've altered line 2 to just `<?php if ( wp_list_pages( "echo=0&child_of=$post->ID" ) ) : ?>` but the page title is not displaying on sub-pages

Comment: How deep is your page hierarchy? i.e. are their children who are also parents?

Comment: There may be grandchildren in the future, but right now it's just parents and children (2 levels of pages)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I really don't think it is wise to base this condition on string comparison of `wp_list_pages` output. There is `wp_list_pages` filter, so any plugin/theme may change this output and break this condition.

Comment: I did not think `wp_list_page` was necessary to accomplish this but both yours and  @KrzysiekDróżdż answers were utilizing it and it seemed to make sense...just a bit more complicated than I needed.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I use `wp_list_pages` for my own sites, but that's a fair point & agree on using `get_pages` for certainty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent ): ?>
<h1><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent); ?></h1>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php else: ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php if ( get_pages( array('child_of' => $post->ID) ) ): ?>
<h2>select a sub-page</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Something like this should do the job. Not tested, sa few bugs/typos may sit in there.

Comment: I would use `if ( $pages = wp_list_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'echo' => false ) ) )` and then just echo `$pages` - less hits on the database :)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Yes, but there is no guarantee that `$pages` will be empty string or false if no pages exists. There is also chance that codeview would like to replace `wp_list_pages` with `wp_dropdown_pages` or something else...

Comment: But there is. If there aren't any pages, `$pages` will indeed be empty. And you can use the same arguments with `wp_dropdown_pages` too. Anyway, just what I would do, you're not wrong either.

Comment: answer is not working, **syntax error, unexpected '=>'** on line 6. I'm not sure how to fix/change.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - can you provide a full answer, as that sounds like a good solution too but I don't know how to execute what you've briefly described.

Comment: @codeview Corrected that typo - missing "array(" on that line.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to list the subpages, just the text "select a sub-page" if there are subpages (the wp_list_pages function will be used in a different area of the page).

Comment: @codeview you don't have to list it. Updated my answer.